# Check if object is in the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

var obj = [{ username: 'kim'}, { username: 'ryan'} ];

I want to create an if statement where if theres a 'kim' value on the var obj, it returns true;

Answer (score 0):

You can check with the array util function `find()` if there is such an element in the array. Here is an example:

```
const objs = [{ username: 'kim'}, { username: 'ryan'}];
const result = objs.find(item => item.username === 'kim');
if (typeof result !== 'undefined') {
  console.log(true);
} else {
  console.log(false);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Array.find` or `Array.some`.

- `find`

obj.find((el) => el.username == 'kim')

- `some`

`obj.some((el) => el.username == 'kim') != undefined`

- Or even `Array.reduce

  obj.reduce((rs, el) => el.username == 'kim' || rs, false)

Comment: No need to recreate `.some` (or `.find`) as a `.reduce` operation.